# how to allow proxy pass with same location, with multiple context path

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, proxypass, alpine

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

location /consol {

```
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$) {
        return 405 "Not allowed";
    }
     
    set $consolalb alb.backend;
    proxy_pass http://$consolalb/workspace/;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Custom-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;        
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;      
    }
}
```

I have the scenario where the user request reaches our ngnix container reverse proxy. [www.example.com/consol](http://www.example.com/consol) and it has to forward to backend alb (e.g alb.backend) and the alb is mapped to oracle hyperion application server with the context path /workspace.

with the above configuration I can able to load the initial login page /workspace/index.jsp, along with that getting additional pop ups with different context paths  getting error like page not found. those page not found urls look like [www.example.com/interop](http://www.example.com/interop), [www.example.com/mypage.jsp](http://www.example.com/mypage.jsp) etc. all the popups are having page not found error.

I need some suggetion how to forward [www.example.com/consol](http://www.example.com/consol) incoming user request to http://$consolalb/workspace/; for the first time and subsequent pop request to http://$consolalb/*

Answer (score 0):

Your application generates the URLs in the output it creates. Therefore you need to configure your application to use a correct base URL so that the URLs it generates are correct.